# Is validate delimiters with ColdFusion possible?

Tags: coldfusion

My CF application provide three selections (semicolon, comma or tab) for users to choose to match the delimiters they have in their file. I want to validate what users selected with what delimiter they have in their file. Is there a way to do this?

So if user is using tab delimiters for his text file but he accidentally selected a comma then I will get this error:

Invalid list index 2.
In function `ListGetAt(list, index [, delimiters])`, the value of index, 2, is not a valid as the first argument (this list has 1 elements). Valid indexes are in the range 1 through the number of elements in the list.

I think the only way to avoid this type of error is if I can validate user's delimiters being used in their file but I could not find any example when I searched the web.

Comment: Couldn't you just catch the error and then present a message to the user that their document might be malformed and to ensure that they selected the correct delimiter?

Comment: You mean catching the error using the cftry cfcatch?

Comment: That could work, yea

Comment: What happens if they select commas, meant to select tabs, and the file has both tabs and commas in it? It would probably be better to let them verify that their text is delimited correctly before doing anything with it. I would also recommending trapping the error to prevent too much info leakage.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what kind of data is delimited in the file, so here's just a very simple guessing method:

```
<!--- read file into memory --->
<cfset fileContent = fileRead( expandPath("yourfile.csv") )>

<!--- declare delimiting characters to check, NOTE: due to using "listLen" you may only specify single characters --->
<cfset possibleDelimiters = [ ";", ",", chr(9) ]> <!--- chr(9) = tab --->

<!--- count number of records found for each delimiter --->
<cfset countResults = {}>
<cfloop array="#possibleDelimiters#" index="delimiter">
    <cfset countResults[delimiter] = listLen(fileContent, delimiter)>
</cfloop>

<!--- determine delimiter with the highest count --->
<cfset sortedDelimiters = structSort(countResults, "NUMERIC", "DESC")>
<cfset mostFrequentDelimiter = sortedDelimiters[1]>

<cfoutput>
    Is <code>#encodeForHtml(mostFrequentDelimiter)# (#asc(mostFrequentDelimiter)#)</code> the delimiter?
</cfoutput>
```

However, this will guess terribly if you have text paragraphs in your file due to the frequency of commas in most written languages, so take it with a grain of salt.